# SQL Server *= Operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, operators

Today while inside a client's production system, I found a SQL Server query that contained an unfamiliar syntax.  In the below example, what does the `*=` operator do?  I could not find any mention of it [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx).  The query does execute and return data.  As far as anyone knows, this has been in the system since they were using SQL Server 2000, but they are now running 2005.

```
declare @nProduct int
declare @iPricingType int
declare @nMCC int

set @nProduct = 4
set @iPricingType = 2
set @nMCC = 230

--Build SQL for factor matrix

Select distinct
base.uiBase_Price_ID,
base.nNoteRate, 
base.sDeliveryOpt, 
IsNull(base.nPrice,0) as nPrice, 
IsNull(base.nPrice,0) + Isnull(fact.nFactor,0) as nAdjPrice, 
base.iProduct_ID,
fact.iPosition as fiPosition, 
base.iPosition, 
CONVERT(varchar(20), base.dtDate_Updated, 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), base.dtDate_Updated, 108) as 'dtDate_Updated', 
fact.nFactor, 
fact.nTreasFactor, 
product.sProduct_txt ,  
pfi.sPFI_Name,  
mccprod.nServicing_Fee,  
fact.nNoteRate as fNoteRate,  
mcc.nLRA_Charge as nLRA  
From 
tbl_Base_Prices base, tbl_Factors fact, tbl_Product product, tbl_PFI pfi, tbl_MCC mcc, tbl_MCC_Product mccprod 
Where
base.iProduct_ID = @nProduct  
And base.iProduct_ID *= fact.iProduct_ID 
And base.iPosition *= fact.iPosition 
And base.nNoteRate *= fact.nNoteRate 
And base.iPricing_Type = @iPricingType
And fact.iMCC_ID =  @nMCC
And fact.iProduct_ID = @nProduct
And mcc.iMCC_ID =  @nMCC 
And mcc.iPFI_ID = pfi.iPFI_ID 
And mccprod.iMCC_ID =  @nMCC
And mccprod.iProduct_ID =  @nProduct
And base.iProduct_ID = product.iProduct_ID 
and fact.iPricing_Type= @iPricingType
Order By
base.nNoteRate, base.iPosition
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Remove this code immediately and replace with a left join. This code does not always interpret correctly (Sometimes SQL Server decides it is a cross join) even in SQL Server 2000 and thus can give incorrect results! Also it is deprecated for the future ([Using Outer Joins, SQL Server 2000 documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130907031446/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228(v=sql.80).aspx) archived from [the original](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228(v=sql.80).aspx)).

I'm going to add that in adjusting to left joins you should remove all of those other implicit joins as well. The implicit join syntax has been **obsolete** since 1992, there is no excuse for it still being in production code. And mixing implicit and explicit joins can give unexpected results.

---

Comment: `This code does not always interpret correctly (Sometimes SQL Server decides it is a cross join) even in SQL Server 2000 and thus can give incorrect results! Also it is deprecated for the future.` I know this is very old, but I was wondering if you had documentation that supports this statement? Thanks!

Comment: *The SQL-92 syntax is recommended because it is not subject to the ambiguity that sometimes results from the legacy Transact-SQL outer joins.* From [SQL 2000 BOL: Using Outer Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228(v=sql.80).aspx). The newer versions of that topic don't even mention `*=` and `=*` joins.

Comment: Also (thanks @MikaelEriksson): *Using this syntax for outer joins is discouraged because of the potential for ambiguous interpretation and because it is nonstandard. Instead, specify joins in the FROM clause.* From [SQL 2000 BOL: SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187(v=sql.80).aspx).

Comment: Neither of those references get into the *exact specifics* of the ambiguity, but the fact that even Microsoft documents them as unreliable and capable of producing incorrect / ambiguous results just amplifies the sentiment that you should not be using them. Ever.

Comment: That you @AaronBertrand. SQL Server BOL would be the refernce I had too. I also know from answering questions in forums like this (although SO didn't exist back then) that they produce cross joins in some circumstances which is how I happened to find the reference in BOL many many years ago.

Comment: Just found one minutes ago, rewrote query first and then searched for this archaic term

Answer (score 13):

It is a left outer join,    =*    is a right outer join.

E.g. the following are equal;

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.FK_ID

  SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.ID *= Table2.FK_ID
```

Comment: Actually, they are not always equal. In a simple query like this probably, in a more complex query, there is a good chacne taht the database will interpret it as a cross join instead of a left join. Even the SQL Server 2000 BOL talks about this issue. There is no circumstance where it is appropriate to use the implicit left join syntax in SQL server unless you are using such an early version that explict syntax is not supported.

Comment: It *is* a `CROSS JOIN`. Comma `,` and `CROSS JOIN` are exactly the same thing. It's just the operator which returns a results similar to a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @DaveBoltman `*=` does not denote an operator & comma does not mean cross join when a `*` is present; the entire join-where means something that is not a filter of a cross join.

Comment: @philipxy I stand corrected. You've taught me something - thank you!!

Answer (score 8):

The non-ANSI syntax for outer joins (`*=` and `=*`) is on the official [list of deprecated features that will be removed in the next version of SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(loband).aspx).

> The following SQL Server Database
>   Engine features will not be supported
>   in the next version of SQL Server. Do
>   not use these features in new
>   development work, and modify
>   applications that currently use these
>   features as soon as possible.

The replacement feature is the [ANSI compliant syntax of JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx).

Comment: @spencer7593 I think you are wrong. `*=` and `=*` was proprietary syntax, never in any ANSI/ISO standard.

Answer (score 5):

It's a shorthand join syntax. Take a look at this thread which covers this topic.

[Transact-SQL shorthand join syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557767/transact-sql-shorthand-join-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

I believe those are "non-ANSI outer join operators". Your database compatibility level must be 80 or lower.

Comment: There are ansi, just ansi-89 rather than ansi-92.  They're also EVIL.

Answer (score 0):

That's the older ANSI (ANSI-89) syntax left outer join operator.  I'd recommend not using it - the ANSI syntax is more verbose and is much more readable.

Comment: It's non standard and depricated so not ANSI ;)

Comment: those are ansi-89, not the newer ansi-92

Comment: `*` was never ANSI.