# =* operator in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I was typing along and fat finger something and when I typed

```
=*
```

in the sql window (2008 SSMS connected to a 2005 server) it turned blue as a keyword.

I can not figure out, or google, what this does.  I know *= but not =*

What does this operator do?

Comment: On what keyboard did you fat-finger "=" and "*"?!

Comment: was suppose to be =( as in starting a subquery in a set statement  =(Select

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server \*= Operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983862/sql-server-operator)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`=*` is an old way to write right outer joins.  For example:

```
select  *
from    A
right outer join
        B
on      A.bid = B.id
```

Is written in the old style like:

```
select  *
from    A
,       B
where   A.bid =* B.id
```

Comment: Wow.  Would =* be a left join or right join?  Also it's funny when I try to write the statement I get ---- 
The query uses non-ANSI outer join operators ("\*=" or "=\*"). To run this query without modification, please set the compatibility level for current database to 80 or lower, using stored procedure sp_dbcmptlevel. It is strongly recommended to rewrite the query using ANSI outer join operators (LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN). In the future versions of SQL Server, non-ANSI join operators will not be supported even in backward-compatibility modes.

Comment: `*=` is left outer join, and `=*` is right outer join.  You can find the old syntax in the Sybase documentation here http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@ebt-link;pt=11971?target=%25N%15_13070_START_RESTART_N%25.  SQL Server and Sybase started as the same product