# * = join in Sqlserver 2008 - Any Performance issue ? Any better alternatives?

Tags: sql-server-2008

What is the better alternative way for using *= join in MS Sqlserver 2008 ? Any better alternative available for this join ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382038/operator-in-sql

Comment: Could you elaborate? Maybe take a screenshot. You may be referencing an outer left or outer right join. *= is an old way of writing an outer left join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an (old) way of writing a left (outer) join. You can write

```
SELECT * FROM TableA, TableB WHERE TableA_ID *= TableB_ID
```

which has the same meaning as

```
SELECT * FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA_ID = TableB_ID
```