# How to rewrite legacy join syntax *= in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, legacy-code

I am trying to rewrite legacy join syntax with new standards.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM es_dbo.tablTypes t
    ,es_dbo.tablReg r
    ,es_dbo.tabl_PRGandCLI p
WHERE t.ClientType *= r.ClientType
    AND p.ID IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ClientID
        FROM esinet_dbo.tablReG
        )
    AND t.ClientType IN (@intClientType)
```

Here is what I am trying.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM es_dbo.tablTypes t
LEFT JOIN es_dbo.tablReg r ON t.ClientType = r.ClientType
LEFT JOIN es_dbo.tabl_PRGandCLI p ON p.ID IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ClientID
        FROM es_dbo.tablReG
        )
```

I am getting same no of records whether I use LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN in 2nd part of query. Can anyone explain

Comment: You're getting the same records because the data that is there means there's no difference. I think your rewrite should be inner joins, not left, and I don't think you need the in-subquery

Comment: I am not sure if `es_dbo.tabl_PRGandCLI` should be used in INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN. There is no joining condition

Comment: If there's no joining condition then I think it is a cross

Comment: I think the query you tried replicates the logic correctly.   Can you find an example of a row of data that was returned by the old query that is not returned by your new query?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM es_dbo.tablTypes t
    left join es_dbo.tablReg r on t.ClientType = r.ClientType
WHERE t.ClientType IN (@intClientType)
   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM esinet_dbo.tablReG p WHERE r.ClientID = p.ID)
```

1) <strike>I assumed @intClientType is a scalar value, so no need for IN</strike>

2) removed DISTINCT and subquery as you check for existence. EXISTS should be faster as it involves finding the first element, rather than doing some sorting for DISTINCT.

3) *= was replaced with LEFT JOIN, based on discussion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983862/sql-server-operator).

Comment: Original query selects multiple columns. I just replaced with COUNT(*) to see result. without parameter value, query was returning over 100 million records.

Comment: Ok, I have updated suggested query replacement accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It is neither inner join nor left join according to query it seems like cross join so you can use following query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM es_dbo.tablTypes t
LEFT JOIN es_dbo.tablReg r ON t.ClientType = r.ClientType,
es_dbo.tabl_PRGandCLI p WHERE p.ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ClientID
    FROM es_dbo.tablReG
    )
```