# SQL 2003 to 2014 conversion for the operator *=

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Please help to convert below query from Sql2003 to 2014, the operator *= does not working, when replace left out join it ignore null rows.

```
SELECT REJECT_CODE,IsNull(SUM(REJ_M2),0.00) as Rejection 
FROM   dbo.Reject_Code a, dbo.QA_Rej_Det1 b 
WHERE  a.REJ_RKEY *= b.REJ_CODE and b.CUSTOMER_PART_DESC = 'XXXXX'  
GROUP BY REJECT_CODE order by REJECT_CODE
```

Comment: "The implicit join syntax has been obsolete since 1992" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983862/sql-server-operator

Comment: There was no 2003 product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*= operator is deprecated. You should start using ANSI syntax like:

```
SELECT REJECT_CODE,IsNull(SUM(REJ_M2),0.00) as Rejection 
FROM   dbo.Reject_Code a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QA_Rej_Det1 b 
ON a.REJ_RKEY = b.REJ_CODE AND b.CUSTOMER_PART_DESC = 'XXXXX'  
GROUP BY REJECT_CODE order by REJECT_CODE
```