# Visual Studio SQL Deployment Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to generate a script from Visual Studio --> Publish-->Generate script. it is failing for on server with an error "Incorrect Syntax Near *=" and same is getting generated for other server. How I can find what could be wrong. is there a way to get the exact error as Data Tool windows doesn't show much details.

[image]

SQL Deployment Script generation using Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

JOIN syntax as `*=` or `=*` was [deprecated in SQL Server 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms143729(v=sql.100)) and [is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/2014/database-engine/discontinued-database-engine-functionality-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2014#Denali) in higher versions
[image]

It is highly recommended to use ANSI JOINS instead of this unsupported, treated as a bad practice syntax. Use `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, `FULL JOIN`.

see also [SQL Server *= Operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983862/sql-server-operator)

If you don't get such error on some of managed servers I guess it's because there is  a very old version of SQL Server installed. On newer SQL Server instances you won't be able to use such code.