# SQL "*=" operator

Tags: sql, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transact-SQL shorthand join syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557767/transact-sql-shorthand-join-syntax)

I ran across a T-SQL script that does something like this in the where clause:

```
...
where o.obj_code *= c.prv_code
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on the *= operator.  Can anyone explain its use and maybe point to some documentation on it?  Is this specific to T-SQL?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557767/transact-sql-shorthand-join-syntax (among many others iirc)

Comment: Thanks for linking to the duplicate, for some reason that didn't come up in my searches.

Comment: Its shorthand notation for job-security by obscurity.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428144/sql-what-does-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deprecated Outer Join syntax.
In on the list of [Deprecated Engine Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx):

> Use of `*=` and `=*`
>   Use ANSI join syntax. For more
>   information, see [FROM (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx).

Comment: +1 for mentioning it's going the way of the dodo...

Answer (score 1):

It's an old way to do outer joins. Here's an [article that explains in more detail](http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/40027/sql_server_40027.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is old non-ANSI outer join syntax. Don't use it. Heres and [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122(loband).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

*= is an old way to do left outer joins that came from Oracle. I found a mention to it in the SQL Server docs once as something they highly recommended not doing.

Here's some info on it from MS:

[Transact-SQL Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196318%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Oracle is hardly the only offender, here.

Comment: Oracle? Sybase, yes. Oracle is where o.obj_code = c.prv_code(+)

Comment: True, but it's where I learned it from so it sticks in my head to blame Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

That's the old syntax for a left outer join, and was deprecated from SQL Server 2005 upwards.