# SQL query symbol "*="

Tags: join, replace, using

What does the symbol `"*="` stand for in a `SELECT` statement? How does this affect the performance? Can we replace it with `JOINS`?

Thanks
STR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some database systems,

```
SELECT ... FROM a, b WHERE a.field1 *= b.field2
```

is an old syntax for a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.field1 = b.field2
```

Microsoft SQL Server, for example, [considers the *= syntax to be deprecated since version 2005](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2008/09/13/deprecation-of-old-style-join-syntax-only-a-partial-thing.aspx).

So yes, you *can* replace `*=` with a JOIN. In fact, you *should*. (I doubt that it affects performance in any relevant way, but your queries might stop working in newer versions of your database engine.)

Comment: Thanks Heinzi. I also found other posts related to this under:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731413/sql-operator

Answer (score 0):

In some implementations of SQL, a SELECT statement that has a assignment operator(`=`) can be used to create the relationship between a column heading and the expression that defines the values for the column.

So an example might be:

```
SELECT name = 'renamed_column_name'
FROM users
```

More Info:

Unfortunately the `=` operator can mean both assign and equality.

For assignment:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT;
SET @Counter = 1;
```

For equality:

The `=` is a equality operator states that the left side must equal the right side.

The could mean a value must equal the result returned by a subquery, or a variable must equal a literal, no matter the case... a = b means that a and b have to have the same value.

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
```